# How to select a specific button in a different language/with not much information using pywinauto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I have a script where I am automating a specific workflow using several programs on windows.
Basically it's clicking some menu buttons.

In one case I am doing the following:

`app.child_window(title="Export", control_type="MenuItem").click_input()`

On my own machine it works fine. But once someone else tries it where it's using a different language it results in errors because it cannot find the "Export" name.
Is there some other way I could click this button? Unfortunately there is not AutomationID ("") available for it.

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/atspi/code/pywinauto.element_info.html
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/atspi/code/pywinauto.windows.win32_element_info.html

When I check the list here.

- auto_id: "" - used by other buttons
- children: I have other buttons that use the same children.
- class_name: "QAction" - is used by other buttons
- control_id: seems to be used by other buttons
- descendants: not sure - but I think also used by other buttons
- dump_window(): not sure
- enabled: not relevant
- filter_with-depth: not sure
- framwork_id: "Qt" - used by other buttons
- name: "Export" - but for other languages it will be different name
- parent: used by other buttons
- process_id: seems to always change?
- rectangle: not sure
- rich_text: not sure but I don't think it's relevant?
- set_cache_strategy: not sure
- top_level_parent: used by other buttons